# Typing Yale Romanization

Tags: cantonese, romanization, yale-romanization

I learned Cantonese using Yale Romanization, but I'm unable to type it easily because of the accent marks representing the tones.  Is there a quick and easy way to do this without using a special character set or keyboard layout?  If not, what's the best (read: simplest) character set to use that will give me the accents I need for Yale Romanization?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows but it would certainly be useful if there were some answers for OSX or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There are [these](http://rescomp.stanford.edu/~domingo2/Chinese.html) input plugins for OSX (There is one for Jyutping and one for Yale). I have never used them myself.